# Issue in displaying '<' symbol dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to display a string with '<' symbol in it, the part of string after the symbol gets ignored. However, when I log it in `console` it's displayed correctly. Here's a snippet of the issue:

```js
console.log('display<hide');//Displays Full text
document.getElementById('somediv').innerHTML='display<hide';//Removes remaining part
```

```html
<div id="somediv">
        
</div>
```

Why does this happen?

#### Edit:

I am aware about `&lt` and `&gt` in HTML, but my question is regarding the issue in displaying `<` as I had **no issues** displaying `>` with innerHTML

Comment: Your string is being parsed by the browser's HTML parser. You have to use HTML entity notation to include `<` in HTML, `&lt;` Or, use `innerText`.

Comment: @Pointy but i had no issues with ````>```` operator, it was displayed in the output.

Comment: OK, but `>` is not the same character as `<`.

Comment: Yes, they are different but if ````<```` is converted to ````&lt;```` then why isn't ````>```` converted to ````&gt;````.

Comment: Browsers allow `>` in running content, but not `<`.

Comment: Well that answers the question, Thanks :)

Comment: Personally I would encode `>` as `&gt;` just as a good practice. In fact I generally encode `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, and `'`.  It doesn't hurt anything and that may be necessary in weird browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening bracket in your string is parsed as malformed HTML then `<hide` gets ignored: so either you use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` or you change the `<` character into its HTML entity `&lt;`

Answer (score 3):

Switch to innerText:

```
document.getElementById('somediv').innerText='display<hide';
```

< and > are reserved characters in HTML for tags.

Comment: Yup that works but '>' operator was displayed with innerHTML too